# why does my Neural network not work with MNIST dataset?

Tags: python, neural-network, mnist

i have written the attached neural net twice reading each line carefully i have taken reference from tariq rashid's book how to train your neural network
in the book hi claims to have an accuracy of upto 95%.
But my code does not converge, accuracy revolves around 10% which means it is guessing randomly.
please help

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.special
from random import *

class NeuralNetwork:
def __init__(self,inp_layer,hid_layer,out_layer):
    self.inp_layer = inp_layer
    self.hid_layer = hid_layer
    self.out_layer = out_layer
    self.learning_rate = 0.1

    self.weights_ih = np.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.hid_layer, 0.5),(self.hid_layer, self.inp_layer))
    self.weights_ho = np.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.out_layer, 0.5),(self.out_layer, self.hid_layer))

    self.bias_h = np.random.rand(self.hid_layer,1)
    self.bias_o = np.random.rand(self.out_layer,1)

    #self.activation = lambda x: scipy.special.expit(x)
    #self.d_activation = lambda x: x*(1-x)
    self.activation = lambda x: np.tanh(x)
    self.d_activation = lambda x: 1-(x*x)

def train(self,inps,targs):
    inputs = np.array(inps,ndmin=2).T
    targets = np.array(targs,ndmin=2).T

    hidden_inputs = np.dot(self.weights_ih, inputs)
    hidden_inputs += self.bias_h
    hidden_outputs = self.activation(hidden_inputs)
    output_inputs = np.dot(self.weights_ho, hidden_outputs)
    output_inputs += self.bias_o
    outputs = self.activation(output_inputs)

    output_errors = targets - outputs
    hidden_errors = np.dot(self.weights_ho.transpose(),output_errors)

    delta_weights_ho = self.learning_rate*np.dot((output_errors*self.d_activation(outputs)),hidden_outputs.transpose())
    delta_weights_ih = self.learning_rate*np.dot((hidden_errors*self.d_activation(hidden_outputs)),inputs.transpose())
    delta_bias_o = self.learning_rate*(output_errors*self.d_activation(outputs))
    delta_bias_h = self.learning_rate*(hidden_errors*self.d_activation(hidden_outputs))

    self.weights_ho += delta_weights_ho
    self.weights_ih += delta_weights_ih

    self.bias_o += delta_bias_o
    self.bias_h += delta_bias_h

def predict(self,inps):
    inputs = np.array(inps,ndmin=2).T

    hidden_inputs = np.dot(self.weights_ih, inputs)
    hidden_inputs += self.bias_h
    hidden_outputs = self.activation(hidden_inputs)
    output_inputs = np.dot(self.weights_ho, hidden_outputs)
    output_inputs += self.bias_o
    outputs = self.activation(output_inputs)

    return outputs
```

and here is implementation of the above neural network

```
from NeuralNetwork import *
from random import *
import numpy as np

nn = NeuralNetwork(784,200,10)

file = open('mnist_train.csv')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
tFile = open('mnist_test.csv')
tLines = tFile.readlines()
tFile.close()

for epoch in range(7):
    shuffle(lines)
    for line in range(60000):
        data = lines[line].split(',')
        inputs = (np.asfarray(data[1:])/255)
        targets = np.zeros(10)
        targets[int(data[0])] = 0.99
        nn.train(inputs,targets)

    fitness = 0
    for tLine in range(10000):
        tData = tLines[tLine].split(',')
        tInputs = (np.asfarray(tData[1:])/255)
        tTarget = int(tData[0])
        prediction = nn.predict(tInputs)
        if np.argmax(prediction)==tTarget:
            fitness+=1

    print('epoch',epoch,'complete','fitness',fitness/1000)
```

here is the output:

```
epoch 0 complete fitness 0.124
epoch 1 complete fitness 0.169
epoch 2 complete fitness 0.138
epoch 3 complete fitness 0.144
epoch 4 complete fitness 0.178
epoch 5 complete fitness 0.231
epoch 6 complete fitness 0.162
```

the fitness should be increasing after every epoch

Comment: It might be illuminating to print out the cost fcn at set steps during training to see what's happening to it.

Comment: yes and overall cost is not improving...it is showing random numbers each time

Comment: infact it is showing the overall accuracy after each epoch, it should be going up but instead it revolves around 10%

Comment: What do you mean "random numbers each time"? Is it just choosing totally random numbers? In what range? Is it increasing?

Comment: no the accuracy is not increasing

Comment: I mean the cost. Can you post what your cost is doing?

Comment: yes i will edit the question

Comment: fitness is accuracy right...the accuracy is not the cost, I'd like to know what the cost function is doing.

Comment: how can i calculate that ?

Comment: It might be best to learn more about what a cost function is and how to calculate it before attempting to write your own neural network. It's a core concept that basically lies at the heart of everything. After all, the whole goal of the machine learning algorithm is to minimize the cost function. I suggest you look up some tutorials online about machine learning, most of them will talk about the cost function and what it does.

Comment: ok thanks for the advice

Comment: Mini batches? Code looks like it’s adjusting weights and biases after every image. It might be worth summing a few and THEN adjusting the weights? Or else reduce the learning rate a bit to prevent it from just oscillating.

Comment: shouldn't it be more efficient if i adjust weights and biases after every image ?